# Who has written Madhurashtakam and what is its meaning?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, stotra, vallabhacharya

Who has written Madhurashtakam and what is its meaning? Which deity is addressed in this ashtakam?

Comment: [This site](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_krishna-madhurashtakam-adharam_madhuram.php) says it was composed by Vallahachari on Sri Krishna.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Madhurashtakam](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_krishna-madhurashtakam-adharam_madhuram.php) was written by [Vallabha Acharya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vallabha_Acharya), the founder of the Pushti Marga and philosophy of Shuddhaadvaita. It is written in respect of Lord Krishna.

> अधरं मधुरं वदनं मधुरं नयनं मधुरं हसितं मधुरम् ।
>
> हृदयं मधुरं गमनं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥१॥
>
> Adharam Madhuram Vadanam Madhuram Nayanam Madhuram Hasitam Madhuram |
>
> Hrdayam Madhuram Gamanam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipater-Akhilam Madhuram ||1||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 1.1: (O Krishna) Your Lips are Sweet and Charming, Your Face is Sweet and Charming, Your Eyes are Sweet and Charming and Your Laughter is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 1.2: (O Krishna) Your Heart is Sweet and Charming and Your Going is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> वचनं मधुरं चरितं मधुरं वसनं मधुरं वलितं मधुरम् ।
>
> चलितं मधुरं भ्रमितं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥२॥
>
> Vacanam Madhuram Caritam Madhuram Vasanam Madhuram Valitam Madhuram |
>
> Calitam Madhuram Bhramitam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipater-Akhilam Madhuram ||2||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 2.1: (O Krishna) Your Speech is Sweet and Charming, Your Nature is Sweet and Charming, Your Garments are Sweet and Charming and Your Bent Posture is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 2.2: (O Krishna) Your Walking is Sweet and Charming and Your Creation of Confusion is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> वेणुर्मधुरो रेणुर्मधुरः पाणिर्मधुरः पादौ मधुरौ ।
>
> नृत्यं मधुरं सख्यं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥३॥
>
> Vennur-Madhuro Rennur-Madhurah Paannir-Madhurah Paadau Madhurau |
>
> Nrtyam Madhuram Sakhyam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipater-Akhilam Madhuram ||3||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 3.1: (O Krishna) Your Flute is Sweet and Charming, Your Flowers ( with Pollen ) are Sweet and Charming, Your Hands are Sweet and Charming and Your Feet are Sweet and Charming,
>
> 3.2: (O Krishna) Your Dance is Sweet and Charming and Your Friendship is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> गीतं मधुरं पीतं मधुरं भुक्तं मधुरं सुप्तं मधुरम् ।
>
> रूपं मधुरं तिलकं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥४॥
>
> Giitam Madhuram Piitam Madhuram Bhuktam Madhuram Suptam Madhuram |
>
> Ruupam Madhuram Tilakam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipater-Akhilam Madhuram ||4||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 4.1: (O Krishna) Your Singing is Sweet and Charming, Your Drinking is Sweet and Charming, Your Eating is Sweet and Charming and Your Sleeping is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 4.2: (O Krishna) Your Form is Sweet and Charming and Your Mark on Forehead is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> करणं मधुरं तरणं मधुरं हरणं मधुरं रमणं मधुरम् ।
>
> वमितं मधुरं शमितं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥५॥
>
> Karannam Madhuram Tarannam Madhuram Harannam Madhuram Ramannam Madhuram |
>
> Vamitam Madhuram Shamitam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipater-Akhilam Madhuram ||5||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 5.1: (O Krishna) Your Acts are Sweet and Charming, Your Carrying Over is Sweet and Charming, Your Stealing is Sweet and Charming and Your Divine Love Play is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 5.2: (O Krishna) Your Exuberance is Sweet and Charming and Your Relaxation is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> गुञ्जा मधुरा माला मधुरा यमुना मधुरा वीची मधुरा ।
>
> सलिलं मधुरं कमलं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥६॥
>
> Gun.jaa Madhuraa Maalaa Madhuraa Yamunaa Madhuraa Viicii Madhuraa |
>
> Salilam Madhuram Kamalam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipaterakhilam Madhuram ||6||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 6.1: (O Krishna) Your Humming is Sweet and Charming, Your Garland is Sweet and Charming, Your Yamuna is Sweet and Charming and Your Waves (of Yamuna) is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 6.2: (O Krishna) Your Water (of Yamuna) is Sweet and Charming and Your Lotus is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> गोपी मधुरा लीला मधुरा युक्तं मधुरं मुक्तं मधुरम् ।
>
> दृष्टं मधुरं शिष्टं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥७॥
>
> Gopii Madhuraa Liilaa Madhuraa Yuktam Madhuram Muktam Madhuram |
>
> Drssttam Madhuram Shissttam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipaterakhilam Madhuram ||7||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 7.1: (O Krishna) Your Gopis (Cowherd Girls) are Sweet and Charming, Your Divine Play is Sweet and Charming, Your Togetherness is Sweet and Charming and Your Setting Free is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 7.2: (O Krishna) Your Glance is Sweet and Charming and Your Courtesy is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.
>
> गोपा मधुरा गावो मधुरा यष्टिर्मधुरा सृष्टिर्मधुरा ।
>
> दलितं मधुरं फलितं मधुरं मधुराधिपतेरखिलं मधुरम् ॥८॥
>
> Gopaa Madhuraa Gaavo Madhuraa Yassttir-Madhuraa Srssttir-Madhuraa |
>
> Dalitam Madhuram Phalitam Madhuram Madhura-Adhipaterakhilam Madhuram ||8||
>
> Meaning:
>
> 8.1: (O Krishna) Your Gopas (Cowherd Boys) are Sweet and Charming, Your Cows are Sweet and Charming, Your Staff is Sweet and Charming and Your Creation is Sweet and Charming,
>
> 8.2: (O Krishna) Your Breaking is Sweet and Charming and Your Making is Sweet and Charming; Everything about You is Sweet and Charming, O Lord of Sweetness.

Answer (score 4):

> The Madhurastakam is a Sanskrit composition in devotion of Krishna,
>   composed by the Hindu Bhakti philosopher-poet Sripad Vallabha Acharya.
>   Mahaprabhu Srimad Vallabhacharya is one of the greatest
>   sage-philosophers of India, who belonged to a Telugu family, was one
>   of the foremost followers of Bhakthi Marga and established his
>   philosophy of Pushti Marga in North India during the 16th century. His
>   Bhakthi was much more than devotion. It was becoming mad in the
>   thought of God. According to him the devotee does not see anything
>   except his Lord everywhere. Madhurashtakam written by him sees
>   sweetness in his lord inch by inch.

[Source 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhurastakam), [Source 2](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Madhurashtakam)

> Adharam Madhuram, Vadanam Madhram,
>
> Nayanam Madhuram, Hasitham Maduram,
>
> Hrudhayam Madhuram, Gamanam Maduram,
>
> Madhuradhipather Akhilam Madhuram., 1
>
> Sweet are thine lips, Krishna,
>
> So are thine sweet cherubic face,
>
> Sweet are thine jet black eyes, Krishna
>
> So is thine soulful laugh, Sweet is thine loving heart, Krishna
>
> So is thine beautiful gait,
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet.
>
> Vachanam Madhuram, Charitham Madhuram,
>
> Vasanam Madhuram, Valitham Madhuram,
>
> Chalitham Madhuram, Bramitham Maduram,
>
> Madhurathipather Akhilam Madhuram., 2
>
> Sweet are thine sweetest words, Krishna,
>
> So is thine divine story.
>
> Sweet is the place of your stay, Krishna,
>
> So is thine greatness,
>
> Sweet are thine movements, Krishna,
>
> So is thine confusion.
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet.
>
> Venur Madhura, Renur Madhura,
>
> Panir Madhura, Padhou Madhura,
>
> Nrithyam Madhuram, Sakhyam MadhuraM,
>
> Madurathipather Akhilam Madura., 3
>
> Sweet is thine flute, Krishna,
>
> So is thine foot-dust,
>
> Sweet are thine hands Krishna,
>
> So are thine feet.
>
> Sweet is thine dance Krishna,
>
> So is thine friendship.
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet
>
> Geetham Madhuram, Peetham Madhuram,
>
> Bhuktham Madhuram,Suptham Madhuram,
>
> Roopam Madhuram, Thilakam Madhuram
>
> Madhurathipather akhilam Madhuram., 4
>
> Sweet is thine song, Krishna,
>
> So is what you drink,
>
> Sweet is what you eat, Krishna,
>
> So is your sleep,
>
> Sweet are thine looks, Krishna,
>
> So is thine Thilaka, Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet.
>
> Karanam Madhram, Tharanam Madhuram,
>
> Haranam Madhuram, Ramanam Madhuram,
>
> Vamitham Madhuram, Samitham Maduram,
>
> Madhurathipather akhilam Madhuram., 5
>
> Sweet are thine deeds, Krishna,
>
> So is thine path of salvation,
>
> Sweet is thine theft, Krishna,
>
> So is thine play of love,
>
> Sweet are thine oblations, Krishna,
>
> So is thine tranquility,
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet
>
> Gunja Madhura, Mala Madhura,
>
> Yamuna Madhura, Veechi Madhura,
>
> Salilam Madhuram, Kamalam Madhuram,
>
> Madhurathipather akhilam Madhuram., 6
>
> Sweet is thine necklace of berries, Krishnam
>
> So is thine garland,
>
> Sweet is thine river Yamuna, Krishna, So are the ripples in the river,
>
> Sweet is thine water, Krishna,
>
> So is the lotus in the water,
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet
>
> Gopi Madhura, Leela Madhura,
>
> Yuktham Madhuram, Muktham Madhuram,
>
> Drishtam Madhuram,Sishtam Madhram,
>
> Madhurathipather akhilam Madhuram., 7
>
> Sweet are thine Gopis, Krishna,
>
> So is thine playful sport,
>
> Sweet are thine right thoughts,Krishna,
>
> So is thine salvation,
>
> Sweet is what you see, Krishna,
>
> So is what is left out,
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet
>
> Gopa Madhura, Gavo Madhura,
>
> Yashtir Madhura, Srushtir Madhra,
>
> Dhalitham Madhram, Phalitham Madhuram,
>
> Madhurathipather akhilam Madhuram., 8
>
> Sweet are thine Gopas, Krishna,
>
> So are thine cows, Sweet is thine staff, Krishna,
>
> So is thine creation,
>
> Sweet is what you trample, Krishna,
>
> So are thine jokes,
>
> Hey king of all sweetness in this world,
>
> Everything about Thee is sweet

[Source](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Madhurashtakam)

Answer (score 2):

**The *Madhurasthakam*, composed by Sri Vallabhacharya(1478 A.D), is a unique stotra, describing the Sweetness of Shri Krishna.
Madhurashtakam was originally written in Sanskrit and is easily understood. Only one word, madhuram, is repeated seven times each in this ashtakam (poem with eight verses)!
The Madhurasthakam uses just one adjective, “madhuram”, meaning sweet or beautiful etc., to describe the lovely attributes of Lord Sri Krishna’s beautiful form, who is the master of Sweetness and Sweetness personified.**

Please Click for more about the Versus and meaning https://mightykrishna.wordpress.com/2018/09/02/madhurastakam-the-sweetness-of-bhagawan-shri-krishna/

[image]

Comment: Link alone answers are not recommended. You should post meaning of Astakam. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)